# How to download file from IPFS in Python

Tags: python, ipfs

I am using a scenario where uploading encrypted file to the ipfs, now I wanted it to download and then decrypt.
Is there any way to download file using python?

Comment: Any IPFS Python library probably will do. Is there anything you're having trouble with?

Comment: You can use ipfs-api library https://pypi.org/project/ipfs-api/

Answer (score 3):

you can use python wrapper over IPFS to interact with IPFS. you can download it from here

```
https://github.com/ipfs/py-ipfs-api.git

import ipfsapi
api = ipfsapi.connect('127.0.0.1', 5001)
```

To add a file

```
new_file = api.add('new.txt')
```

The response will be like

```
 {'Name': 'new.txt', 'Hash': 'QmWvgsuZkaWxN1iC7GDciEGsAqphmDyCsk3CVHh7XVUUHq', 'Size': '28'}
```

In order to see the content of file you call

```
 api.cat('QmWvgsuZkaWxN1iC7GDciEGsAqphmDyCsk3CVHh7XVUUHq')
```

Answer (score 3):

## I think this will help:

1. first install ipfs python library: **pip install ipfs-api**
2. connect to ipfs peer. This assume that you have installed ipfs on your machine
   and the ipfs daemon is running OR instead connect via infura with no need of running a daemon. This also depends how you uploaded the file.
3. Once you are connected to the peer now use get function with ipfs hash as an inputs
   to download ipfs file
4. Than you are  done and the file will be stored in the current directory(where your python script is located)

for more can use the documantation https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-ipfs-api/latest/python-ipfs-api.pdf.

**Here is the code:**

```
import ipfsApi
api = ipfsApi.Client(host='https://ipfs.infura.io', port=5001)
#OR
#api = ipfsApi.Client(host='http://127.0.0.1', port=5001)
api.get('Qm... Your IPFS Hash')
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use the IPyFS libraries in python.

- This is IPFS example URL: https://github.com/837477/IPyFS/tree/dev/examples/nft_image_uploader
- Git: https://github.com/837477/IPyFS

You can easily upload your nft images. In the example, you should be setting your environments.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
nftmu = NFTMetadataUploader(
    host="http://localhost",
    port=5001,
    metadata_folder="metadata",
    images_folder="images",
    ipfs_folder="test01",
    network_interval_seconds=0.03)

nftmu.check_folders()
nftmu.upload()
print("Done")
```

Maybe you can catch the necessary value in the code.